# Elixir List of Tuples to List of Strings

Tags: elixir

I want to take

```
[{'O', 'L'}, {'E', 'L'}, {'O', 'H'}, {'E', 'L'}, {'E', 'H'}]
```

and change it to

```
["OL", "EL", "OH", "EL", "EH"]
```

but I am not seeing how. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
Enum.map(my_list, fn {a, b} -> List.to_string([a, b]) end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `for` comprehension and string interpolation:

```
iex(1)> list = [{'O', 'L'}, {'E', 'L'}, {'O', 'H'}, {'E', 'L'}, {'E', 'H'}]
[{'O', 'L'}, {'E', 'L'}, {'O', 'H'}, {'E', 'L'}, {'E', 'H'}]
iex(2)> for {a, b} <- list, do: "#{a}#{b}"
["OL", "EL", "OH", "EL", "EH"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this succinctly using [comprehensions](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) and the [`<<>>`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1) operator.

```elixir
for {[a], [b]} <- list, do: <<a::utf8, b::utf8>>
```

Note that `'A'` syntax is a character list, equivalent to a list of unicode code-points. You can use the extracted codepoint with the `utf8` option to the `<<>>` operator to build the corresponding string.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that in Elixir, single-quotes designate character lists, so `'O' != "O"`.  So the solution to your question would look different depending on whether or not you use single-quotes (i.e. character lists) in your tuples (as you wrote), or if you had double-quoted strings, e.g. `[{"O", "L"}, ...]`

If you want to output character lists, then you can convert the tuples to a list and then join the lists using `++`.  This works because `'O'` and `'L'` are themselves lists.

```
iex> l = [{'O', 'L'}, {'E', 'L'}, {'O', 'H'}, {'E', 'L'}, {'E', 'H'}]
iex(5)> Enum.map(l, &Tuple.to_list/1) |> Enum.map(fn [x, y] -> x ++ y end)
['OL', 'EL', 'OH', 'EL', 'EH']
```

If you are dealing with strings from the get-go and you had intended to start with double-quoted strings, then you can join the list of characters using `Enum.join/2`:

```
iex> l = [{"O", "L"}, {"E", "L"}, {"O", "H"}, {"E", "L"}, {"E", "H"}]
iex> Enum.map(l, &Tuple.to_list/1) |> Enum.map(fn chars -> Enum.join(chars) end)
["OL", "EL", "OH", "EL", "EH"]
```

If you need to solve this exactly as written, you can add a `to_string/1` to your conversion:

```
iex> l = [{'O', 'L'}, {'E', 'L'}, {'O', 'H'}, {'E', 'L'}, {'E', 'H'}]
iex> Enum.map(l, &Tuple.to_list/1) |> Enum.map(fn [x, y] -> x ++ y |> to_string() end)
["OL", "EL", "OH", "EL", "EH"]
```

Check out the other answers for more elegant/concise conversions.